# Constraints over arbitrary length sublists using CLP(FD)

Tags: prolog, clpfd, prolog-defaulty

I'm trying to wrap my head around CLP(FD). Here's a simple example of where I'm not sure of the most idiomatic approach. Suppose we have a List of numbers (`L`), with some numbers already filled, like this.

```
L = [_, _, _, 3, _, _, _, 4, _, _, 2, _]
```

And I want to say something like, the numbers both left and right of a fixed one must sum up that number. A possible solution for the above, would be:

```
L = [0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0]
```

There are, of course, other solutions. My first approach would be something like:

1. Search for the first *pivot* number;
2. Get the left and right sublists of the *pivot*;
3. `Append` both lists;
4. Using the predicate `sum/3`, constrain the resulting list to be `#=` to the pivot.

Would this be ideomatic? Am I missing something more evident?

---

**Level 2.** I think the predicate `sum/3` does most of the work. Let's change the problem a little bit:

*A continuous string of 1's to the left and right of the pivot must sum up to the pivot.*

So given this:

```
L = [_, _, _, 3, _, _, _, 5, _, _, 2, _]
```

A possible solution would be:

```
L = [0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 0]
```

And now it's trickier... I would say something along the lines of, *the appended left and right sublists of pivot N must contain a sublist of 1's of length N*. Does this make sense? How would I say something along those lines using CLP(FD)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## "The solution that could have been"

Your reasoning is perfectly correct and will work.

Nevertheless, it falls short in a critical aspect: Your description is currently very **imperative**, and if you implement this in the way you describe, then you will be able to solve *given* instances, but you will *not* be able to use *the same* program to **generate** such puzzle instances.

Let me explain in more detail what I mean.

## Clean representation

We start with the **representation** of such puzzles. You are currently using:

```
L = [_, _, _, 3, _, _, _, 4, _, _, 2, _]
```

This is called a **defaulty** representation because you cannot cleanly distinguish the different cases. If you think logically, and think of this is an "instance" of the puzzle, then any **more special** case of this term *must* be regarded as a *more specific* case of the instance, for example a partial or complete *solution*. But in this representation, that's *not* the case, because instantiating one of the arguments *further* suddenly turns it into a completely different instance instead of only a more specific manifestation.

So, here is a **clean** representation of such puzzles:

```
example([?,?,?,p(3),?,?,?,p(4),?,?,p(2),?]).
```

Here, I am distinguishing the two possible cases by different terms. I am using:

- the *atom* `?` for unknown **integers**
- terms of the form `p(P)` to denote the **pivot** element `P`.

Many other representations are possible, and if you need to express variable *sharing*, you could for example use `i(I)` to represent an unknown integer `I`. The point is that you can distinguish the cases by **pattern matching** instead of non-monotonic constructs that test for *instantiations*. This is the key to **general** solutions that can be used in **all directions**.

## Declarative task description

Let us reconsider the imperative description you gave:

- "*Search* for the first pivot number"
- "*Get* the left and right sublists of the pivot"
- "*Append* both lists"

Now let us express this **declaratively**. We must avoid *imperatives* like "search", "get" and "append", because these all imply a particular **direction** of use.

A declarative description could look like this: We are describing **triples** of the form `Lefts`-`Pivot`-`Rights`, where the following holds:

> The sum of integers `Lefts` and `Rights` is **equal to** `Pivot`.

If we manage to write a Prolog program that *describes* such triples and draws a suitable connection from task instances to such triples, then we're done and can use it in all directions.

## Conversion to triples

It's fun to work on clean representations, and we can easily convert them to other forms because we can so easily distinguish the cases. Therefore, let us convert the instances to **triples** now, over which we can reason more easily.

Let us reflect the task representation: It is a **list** of elements. Very often when *describing* lists in Prolog, **DCG notation** ([dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)) comes in handy. So, let us describe tasks and *at the same time* describe the **relation** between task description and triples:

```
is_p_is([Ls|Rest]) -->
        is(Ls),
        is_p_is_(Rest).

is_p_is_([Pivot,Rs]) --> [p(Pivot)], is(Rs).
is_p_is_([Pivot,Rs,Rs|IPIs]) -->
        [p(Pivot)],
        is(Rs),
        is_p_is_(IPIs).

is([])     --> [].
is([_|Is]) --> [?], is(Is).
```

This DCG is the key point of the whole answer.

Here is how you can use it, to see what it describes:

```
?- example(Es),
   phrase(is_p_is(Ls), Es).
Es = [?, ?, ?, p(3), ?, ?, ?, p(4), ?, ?, p(2), ?],
Ls = [[_G902, _G905, _G908], 3, [_G920, _G923, _G926], [_G920, _G923, _G926], 4, [_G938, _G941], [_G938, _G941], 2, [_G950]] ;
false.
```

From this, you see that I have eliminated the complex reasoning of "searching what is where and how far". Instead, it's a simple and general **relation** between instances and lists of the form:

```
[Left0,Pivot0,Right0,Left1,Pivot1,Right1,Left2,...]
```

where the "triples" are implicit and can be grouped as follows:

```
[(Left0,Pivot0,Right0),(Left1,Pivot1,Right1),...]
```

and further, `Right`<sub>n</sub> is **the same** as `Left`<sub>n+1</sub>.

## Posting constraints

Given such lists, posting the **CLP(FD) constraints** is straight-forward:

```
constraints([]).
constraints([Left,Pivot,Right|Rest]) :-
        Left ins 0..sup,
        Right ins 0..sup,
        sum(Left, #=, SL),
        sum(Right, #=, SR),
        Pivot #= SL + SR,
        constraints(Rest).
```

If you want, you *could* use `append/3` here, but why even bother? Using `append/3` incurs some risk of introducing non-termination, whereas CLP(FD) constraints (ideally) **always terminate**, so I am using two `sum/3` constraints instead.

## Extracting the variables

Extracting the variables is also straight-forward:

```
variables([]) --> [].
variables([Left,_,Right|Rest]) -->
        seq(Left),
        seq(Right),
        variables(Rest).

seq([]) --> [].
seq([L|Ls]) --> [L], seq(Ls).
```

## Sample query and answers

Here is an example query and a few answers:

```
?- example(Es),
   phrase(is_p_is(Ls), Es),
   constraints(Ls),
   phrase(variables(Ls), Vs),
   label(Vs).
Es = [?, ?, ?, p(3), ?, ?, ?, p(4), ?, ?, p(2), ?],
Ls = [[0, 0, 0], 3, [0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 3], 4, [0, 1], [0, 1], 2, [1]],
Vs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1] ;
Es = [?, ?, ?, p(3), ?, ?, ?, p(4), ?, ?, p(2), ?],
Ls = [[0, 0, 0], 3, [0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 3], 4, [1, 0], [1, 0], 2, [1]],
Vs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] ;
Es = [?, ?, ?, p(3), ?, ?, ?, p(4), ?, ?, p(2), ?],
Ls = [[0, 0, 0], 3, [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], 4, [0, 1], [0, 1], 2, [1]],
Vs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1] ;
etc.
```

I have highlighted the "triple" representation.

## Generality for the win

Now the crucial point: All of this is **completely general**, and we can use it to **generate** the instances themselves!

Example:

```
?- length(Es, _), phrase(is_p_is(Ls), Es).
Es = [p(_G874)],
Ls = [[], _G874, []] ;
Es = [p(_G877), ?],
Ls = [[], _G877, [_G885]] ;
Es = [p(_G877), p(_G888)],
Ls = [[], _G877, [], [], _G888, []] ;
Es = [?, p(_G880)],
Ls = [[_G877], _G880, []] ;
Es = [p(_G880), ?, ?],
Ls = [[], _G880, [_G888, _G891]] .
```

This is a *natural* by-product of thinking in terms of **relations**, and using **clean representations**.

I leave the more specific second question as the first exercise for you. I hope the principles shown above help you to arrive at a **clean** and **general** solution that lets you extract the utmost advantage of logic programming.

As the second exercise, I leave rewriting the above to use the `i(_)` representation for unknown integers. With such a representation, we could get rid of several disadvantages in the above. For example, extracting the variables would become somewhat more convenient:

```
variables([]) --> [].
variables([L|Ls]) -->
        variable_(L),
        variables(Ls).

variable_(i(I)) --> [I].
variable_(p(_)) --> [].
```

Example:

```
?- phrase(variables([i(X),p(3),i(Y)]), Vs).
Vs = [X, Y].
```

Also, we would not needlessly *duplicate* the remaining variables in such lists.

Further, check this out:

```
?- length(Ls, _), phrase(variables(Ls), Vs).
Ls = Vs, Vs = [] ;
Ls = [i(_2066)],
Vs = [_2066] ;
Ls = [p(_2066)],
Vs = [] ;
Ls = [i(_2072), i(_2082)],
Vs = [_2072, _2082] ;
Ls = [i(_2072), p(_2082)],
Vs = [_2072] ;
Ls = [p(_2072), i(_2076)],
Vs = [_2076] .
```

How does this **pure** relation compare with using *impure* predicates like `exclude/3`? Can you also generate all possible cases with it? See [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) for more information.

## The tough part

As the third and last exercise, I leave the toughest one: Reread what I wrote and find all instances where I am, by using *imperative* wording, *not doing justice to the generality of what is actually implemented*, and *reword it so that it reflects the actual situation*.

I give an example: I say "Extracting the variables", and what could be more natural, right? But I have actually implemented a full-fledged **relation between variables and triples**, and you can use it to:

- *extract* variables from triples
- *test* whether such variables correspond to given triples
- *generate* both variables and triples
- etc.

For example, we can use the *most general query*:

```
?- phrase(variables(Ts), Vs).
Ts = Vs, Vs = [] ;
Ts = [[], _1960, []],
Vs = [] ;
Ts = [[], _1960, [], [], _1978, []],
Vs = [] ;
Ts = [[], _1960, [], [], _1978, [], [], _1996, []],
Vs = [] .
```

That's of course not a very *fair* enumeration, but it goes well beyond *extracting* something, because *nothing at all is even given* in the query.

## How are you idiomatic!

So, to answer your question: In my view, we regard as *most idiomatic* Prolog those solutions which most impressively exhibit the *declarative properties* we expect from **relations** and unique advantages of logic programs, such as:

- being usable in **all directions**
- admitting a reading as being *more specific* or *more general*
- using *names* that reflect the generality of the relations.

An elegant, idiomatic Prolog solution often starts with a clean representation of instances, and descriptive predicate names.

Comment: Now, that's what I call a *beatiful* answer! Very educative, indeed... I am now wraping my head around your DCG description and trying to generalize it to previous approaches I had when specifying lists' structures. I'll eventually post my answer to the second specific question I've made. In the meantime, I'll just wait a couple of days to persuade other people to participate in this thread, before accepting your answer as definitive. Kudos!

Comment: By the way, do you recommend a modern book on Prolog that covers CLP(FD) and meta-programming? Classical text-books, such as [The Art of Prolog](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/art-prolog), although extremely elegant, are not up-to-date with current practices and interpreters' extension points (such as SWI's *term_expansion/2*), and skip CLP(*) entirely. I'm also very interested in understanding the theoretical aspects of CLP(FD) as a generalization of CLP(H).

Comment: Can't *variables/3* be simply defined as `variables --> exclude(integer), append.` ? Or am I missing something? As far as I understand it, the purpose is to have a list of free variables to pass on to *label/1*, right? Hmmm... Or maybe it's just my imperative mind breaking the beautiful symmetric definition again :D

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement, and for posting an insightful question! Please see my profile for a few Prolog links that cover more recent developments. I hope you find them useful! GUPU in particular is well worth a look both for learning *and* teaching Prolog!